# Insert from one Database table to another Database table in ANDROID

Tags: android, sqlite, android-database

How Can I use **insert into/Select** from one Database table to another Database table.
for more explanation I have one Data base with **"UserDB"** name and **"UserTble"** table and another-one with **"WordDB"** and **"WordsTble"** Table name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As they are separated databases, you can't do it using only SQL.

You must make a query from source table, read sequentially all results from the query and insert each record in the target table.

Comment: Dear Sergey, after many researching around "ATTACH DATABASE" and also "Intert/into method", finally I did what you said. thx